# Calculating multiples

Tags: number-theory

"If set S consists of all positive integers that are multiples of both 2 and 7, how many numbers in set S are between 140 and 240, inclusive?"

I can find the numbers manually. But if the range too long to do it manually, I need to do go through a formula. Can anybody help me to with any formula? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you're just searching for the multiples of 14 in a given range...no need of any "formula"...

Comment: Can you do it for the range $[1,N]$? Then you can just take the difference to get your result.

Comment: Arithmetic series with first term$=140$ and the last $238$ with common diff $14$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first number that in $S=\{a_i: 140 \leq a_i \leq 240, \ \  \  14|a_i \  \ \}$   is $140$, thus $a_1=140$, the second is $a_2=154$, the last number in $S$ is $a_n=238$. How one could find $n$, the number of elements in $S$?

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for numbers that are multiples of $a$ **or** $b$, between $m$ and $n$, then it is $f(n)-f(m)$, where $f(n)$ is described below.

Suppose that $c=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.  Then the following formula takes account that the multiples of $c$ are counted twice.   (// is integer division, as in REXX)

$$f(n) = n // a + n // b - a // c $$

On the other hand, if you are searching for numbers that are multiples of $a$ **and** $b$, then you still need to determine the LCM, $c=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$, whence

$$f(n) = n // c$$